# Jquery resizable auto resize children on parent resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, autoresize

I'm using a jQuery UI resizable function so I can resize my elements in the page builder.

How can I auto re-size elements inside my column while I'm re-sizing that column?

```
<div class="block-aq_column_block">
    <div id="element1"></div>
    <div id="element2"></div>
</div>
```

Now while I re-size **block-aq_column_block**, I want all elements inside it to re-size with it.

I know that I should use **alsoResize**, but I just don't know how I can use it when there are multiple child elements. Any tips?

Comment: well i'm sorry but CSS isn't the issue here. JqueryUI is...

Comment: set `width:auto` in `CSS` and it will do the work for you..

Comment: THIS IS NOT CSS PROBLEM!!!!!

Comment: Well then show us the jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

add css to inner blocks :

```
#element1{width: 100%;}
#element2{width: 100%;}
```

with height of inner block may be more complicated.
if hey have the same height - you can set

```
#element1{height: 50%;}
    #element2{height: 50%;}
```

Comment: again, i have no problem with CSS, i need advice on jQueryUI resizeable function